# Average of columns

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array. I want my loop go through every column and add all numbers greater/equal to 1 and find their average. It should stop when it encounters a number less than 1.

**Sample Array:**

```
0 1.0071 0.0031 0.0034
1 2.0062 5.8043 0.6967
2 7.0051 1.0089 0.0013
3 0.0033 6.8843 1.0078
4 0.0039 0.0027 3.0032
5 2.0092 1.0094 2.0535
6 9.4469 1.0099 7.0647
```

**Sample Output:**

Column 2: 
Average is 3.3394 from numbers 0 to 2.
Average is 5.7280 from numbers 5 to 6.

Column 3:
Average is 4.5658 from numbers 1 to 3.
Average is 1.0096 from numbers 5 to 6.

Column 4:
Average is 3.2823 from numbers 3 to 6.

**My code output:**

4.2949 (average of column 2)
4.5658 (average of column 3)
3.2823 (average of column 4)

This is my code so far:

```
for (int j = 1; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
    sum = 0;
    count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       if (data[i][j] >= 1.0) {
          sum += arr[i][j];
          count++;

       }
    }
int i;
if (count!=0){
   for (i=1; i<=1; i++){
       System.out.print(sum/count + "  "); // find avg of entire column
   }
} else {
   System.out.println(0);
}
```

I can only get the average of ALL numbers greater than/equal to 1 in each column. How can I make my code work that it stops when it encounters 0?

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Can you add some sample output that shows how the data would be displayed?  I'm having a hard time understanding exactly how many averages there should be.

Comment: For column 2, do you want the program to stop while reading number 3 (which is <1), or continue to compute "Average is 5.7280 from numbers 5 to 6"?

Comment: It should stop stop cause it encountered <1. So it gives the output for all the numbers greater than 1 (number 0, 1, 2). Then it should move on to number 5 and 6 and output their average since they're greater than 1.

Comment: Okay, I tried to compose an answer based on this behavior. Please take a look and see if it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting

```
else
    break;
```

after if condition.

Comment: You didn't answer the question. That will simply break out of the column he's on and move on to the next column without computing the average of values that may be >1 later on

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code (I have tested it):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double arr[][] = { { 0, 1.0071, 0.0031, 0.0034 }, { 1, 2.0062, 5.8043, 0.6967 }, { 2, 7.0051, 1.0089, 0.0013 },
            { 3, 0.0033, 6.8843, 1.0078 }, { 4, 0.0039, 0.0027, 3.0032 }, { 5, 2.0092, 1.0094, 2.0535 },
            { 6, 9.4469, 1.0099, 7.0647 } };

    for (int j = 1; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
        double sum = 0;
        double count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i][j] >= 1.0) {
                sum += arr[i][j];
                count++;
            } else if(count > 0) {
                System.out.print(sum / count + "  ");
                sum = 0;
                count = 0;
            }
        }
        int i;
        if (count != 0) {
            for (i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
                System.out.print(sum / count + "  "); // find avg of entire
                                                        // column
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't tested your code, but if it works, we could improve the efficiency of the double for loop and matrix retrieval by, perhaps, storing the data in a symmetric matrix and reading through every column instead of every row.